# Prevent deleting lock file using nio

Tags: java, file-locking

We want to prevent other processes from deleting the temp directory of our running application. That way we create a temp directory and a *lock* file in it. The only way I found at that prevents deleting this file is by using `RandomAccessFile`:

```
tempDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory("myapp");
final Path lockFile = Files.createTempFile(tempDirectory, "lock", null);
randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(lockFile.toFile(), "rw");
```

**Is there a way to achieve the same with nio?** I have tried with the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class CreateLock {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final Path path = Paths.get("C:/temp/test");
        Files.createFile(path);
        final FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        channel.lock();

        for (int i = 60; i-- > 0; ) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (!Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
                System.out.println("File is gone");
                break;
            }

            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        }

        channel.close();
    }
}
```

but a second Java application with this code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class DeleteLock {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Path path = Paths.get("C:/temp/test");
        Files.delete(path);
    }
}
```

can delete the file.

Comment: What is the purpose of that lock file? Are you trying to control that only one instance of the application is running? If yes, I would recommend another way, in your application upon startup start a server socket on a particular port, let say 7890, and listen to this port. In case user tries to launch your app again, it will fail, because the network port is in use.

Comment: If you are just protecting temp folder from deletion, I don't understand, why should it be necessary for a temp folder. All files which are not open (controlled by processed) can be deleted upon trying to delete your temp folder with lock file. And only lock file will remain in the empty temp folder.

Comment: @Rafael: we want the temp folder to be kept while the app is running. Why we want to do that is not the topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(lockFile.toAbsolutePath(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
ch.lock();
```

Comment: That's what I've tried on Win10. The file can be deleted.